# How to use protobuf interface in C#

Tags: protocol-buffers, rpc, protobuf-net

I write a .proto file, and it include a service:

```
service ServerService {
    rpc HelloServer (Word) returns (Void);
}
```

Then, I use protobuf-net generate .cs file:

```
public interface IServerService
{
  gt.Void HelloServer(gt.example.Word request);

}
```

But I do not know how to use it. Is there any doc?

Comment: protobuf-net does not include any specific support for the `rpc` stubs - mainly because the protobuf specification itself doesn't define anything here. Basically, google didn't open source the RPC stack that goes hand-in-hand with their use of protobuf

Comment: So, I can not use 'service' and 'rpc' in C#?

Comment: there is no defined implementation in *any* language; it is not specified. If a consensus implementation (at the protocol level) has emerged since last time I looked, I'd be happy to revisit it - but last time I checked there were a half-dozen diverse, scattered and incompatible implementations, each half-working in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

A new standard, [gRPC](https://grpc.io/), is picking up steam and has support in .net core.

Check out this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

The tutorial also links out to other information on gRPC in .NET. The docs are pretty good.